# typescript redux actions: composition vs inheritance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

In the [redux manual for usage with typescript](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript), they define the action types as such:

```
// src/store/chat/types.ts
export const SEND_MESSAGE = 'SEND_MESSAGE'
export const DELETE_MESSAGE = 'DELETE_MESSAGE'

interface SendMessageAction {
  type: typeof SEND_MESSAGE
  payload: Message
}

interface DeleteMessageAction {
  type: typeof DELETE_MESSAGE
  meta: {
    timestamp: number
  }
}

export type ChatActionTypes = SendMessageAction | DeleteMessageAction
```

This is very much a **type composition**.

---

Conversely, You can define them as such:

BaseAction.ts:

```
export interface BaseAction {
  type: any;
  payload: any;
}
```

SpecificAction.ts:

```
export enum SpecificActionType {
  SPECIFIC_ACTION_1 = "action1",
  SPECIFIC_ACTION_2 = "action2",
}

export interface SpecifcAction extends BaseAction {
  type: SpecificActionType;
}

export const SpecificAction1 = (param: SomeType): SpecifcAction => ({
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_1,
  payload: {
    stream
  },
});

export const SpecificAction2 = (param: SomeType): SpecifcAction => ({
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_2,
  payload: {
    uid
  }
});
```

This second **inheritance based** option seems more intuitive to me, as it allows me to create different action files for different aspects of my application - without modifying the original BaseAction.ts file.

As a side note, see how creating a `SpecificAction1` feels a bit like a scala Case Class - if only typescript had this paradigm, it would be nice for intellisense of the `payload` and syntactic sugar for redux's pattern-matching on action types.

Still, you can do something like this on the reducers:

specificReducer.ts:

```
export const mySpecificReducer = (
  state: MyState = initialState,
  action: SpecifcAction 
): MyState => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_1:
      console.log("add stream action");
      return {<change state accordingly>};

    case SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_2:
      return {<change state accordingly>};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### My question: What's the drawback here?

1. It would seem that this better follows the Open/Close principle, although we can argue that.
2. It may add some complexity, but I'm making the assumption that you have multiple aspects that have inherently different actions in your app, so perhaps this helps manage said complexity better.
3. lastly, you manage the ActionTypes better as Enums, and if you use an IDE with intellisense it'll help you manage the options.

Am I shooting myself in the foot without knowing it?

Comment: Does anyone know where's a good place to have a discussion around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was missing / here's the drawback:

Defining actions as such:

actions_inherited.ts

```
export enum SpecificActionType {
  SPECIFIC_ACTION_1 = "action1",
  SPECIFIC_ACTION_2 = "action2",
}

export interface SpecifcAction extends BaseAction {
  type: SpecificActionType;
}

export const SpecificAction1 = (param: SomeType): SpecifcAction => ({
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_1,
  payload: {
    stream
  },
});

export const SpecificAction2 = (param: SomeType): SpecifcAction => ({
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_2,
  payload: {
    uid
  }
});
```

gives you **no compile-time protections or intellisense** whatsoever as to the `payload`.
Conversely, you can define your actions as such:

actions_composition.ts

```
export enum SpecificActionType {
  SPECIFIC_ACTION_1 = "action1",
  SPECIFIC_ACTION_2 = "action2",
}

export interface SpecifcAction1{
  type: SpecificActionType;
  payload:{
    thing: string,
  },
}

export interface SpecifcAction2{
  type: SpecificActionType;
  payload:{
    thing: number,
  },
}

export const SpecificAction1 = (param: string): SpecifcAction1 => ({
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_1,
  payload: {
    thing: param
  },
});

export const SpecificAction2 = (param: number): SpecifcAction2 => ({
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_2,
  payload: {
    thing: param
  }
});

export type SpecificAction = SpecificAction1 | SpecificAction2
```

this second method, gives you a pretty close pattern matching when you do a switch case on your `action.type`.
Or in code:

```
switch (action.type) { // note that we're switching on the `.type`, not the `action`
  case SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_1:
    action // this is a SpecificAction1 with a `.thing` that is a string
    break;

  case SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_ACTION_2:
    action // this is a SpecificAction2 with a `.thing` that is a number
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, I only ever want to define mappings from each action type to a payload shape. So I decided to use discriminated unions and remove as much type system syntax as I could.

Using this approach lets Typescript protect us from writing action creators with the wrong payload, or making typos.

Honestly the hardest part of using Redux on a huge project is writing all the boilerplate, so I try to keep it to a minimum.

```
export type IceCreamActionShapes = {
  type: IceCreamActionTypeKeys.SET_FLAVOR;
  payload: string;
} | {
  type: IceCreamActionTypeKeys.CREATE_FLAVOR;
  payload: IFlavor;
} | {
  type: IceCreamActionTypeKeys.MELT;
}
```

Imo I don't think that any of the complexity of the application should be managed by the redux action dispatch layer. However, your example with `BaseAction` is still very simple. Even if you added domain specific BaseActions like `IceCreamBaseAction` for each duck, it would still be very easy to maintain because it's open/closed.

I always use string enums for action keys. The keys are refactorable and  searchable, and you can add extra context information to the string value.